# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' in VS code

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, anaconda

When I run it in VS Code, it works with no errors

```py
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 9000, app)
```

See here how's it working on my terminal.

```
PS C:\Users\ASUS\t81_558_deep_learning> & C:/Users/ASUS/Anaconda3/Anaconda/python.exe c:/Users/ASUS/t81_558_deep_learning/py/vs.py
 * Running on http://localhost:9000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2020 17:45:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2020 17:45:42] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

However, when I wrote it in VSCode terminal...

```
PS C:\Users\ASUS\t81_558_deep_learning> python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
>>> from flask import Flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Same command in Conda:

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
>>> import flask
>>>
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Visual Studio too, maybe VSCode is not using the correct python interpreter. You can try choosing conda interpreter at the bottom left of the screen in VSCode.